# Drupal 8.6.1 Site and Admin Pages Slow - Long Wait Time

Tags: php, mysql, web, drupal, drupal-8

My Website built on **Drupal 8.6.1 CMS** takes long time to load, every single page of the site including the Drupal admin panel pages takes about **8-9 seconds to load** and appear on the browser. As far as I can identify it might be because of slow server response time. Briefly speaking, the HTML document itself has 5-6 seconds of wait time, i.e. Time to first byte(TTFB) is more than 7000ms, https://www.webpagetest.org/ results **First Byte Time is *F*** for my website. No CSS/JS/Images are taking time to load as per webpagetest results. Even google https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ says the same.

Following are the specifications of the server where my Drupal website is deployed

1. Server is hosted on AWS
2. RAM - 2GB
3. HDD - 1TB
4. OS  - 4.4.0-1066-aws #76-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 16 16:21:21 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
5. Drupal - 8.6.1, Administration Theme - Seven
6. MySQL - Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
7. Web Server - Apache HTTP

Factors considered for slow websites:

1. Slowness can't be at the network level because server is hosted on AWS (ping is good)
2. Server configuration specified above looks fine to me!
3. At PHP level, I've enabled everything necessary for enhancing Drupal website performance.

   A. Browser and proxy cache maximum age - 1 Day (Caching)

   B. Bandwidth optimization enabled
4. **At Database level, I think here the issue lies, because when I do "show full processlist;", for 4-5 seconds series of queries runs in the database.**

I've spent much time debugging the issue but can't get through it and reduce the wait time/slowness of the website. I'm not actually getting what's causing the high wait time!! Attaching the screenshots of webpagetest results as well firebug network wait time. I hope I'll get solutions from the experts.

[webpagetest result - see TTFB and total time to load website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwLW9.png)

[developer tools - network tab - look at wait time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHZzw.png)

Comment: check the services.yml file. You can do some improves there like caching and removing theme debug. (sites/default)

Comment: Thanks @danielarend for your response. services.yml have desired changes related to caching and not having theme debug!!

Comment: How fast is the robots.txt loading ?

Comment: It loads immediately without any delays, but the website takes a lot to load